# Vue - apply transition to menu element

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have this scss code in my vue app. I'm trying to make a smooth transition from left for a menu when the `isVisible` property is set to true but I'm not able to apply the transition I've defined and the menu will instantly appear.
I've done a reserach here on SO and I've found some interesting questions but all of them are using jQuery and css `animation` so they are not really useful.
I'm not a CSS master, any suggestion about?

HTML

```
    <div class="col-12 settings p-3 position-fixed" :class="{ 'show': isVisible }" ref="settings" v-if="isVisible">
      <h4>Settings</h4>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.settings {
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  &.show {
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with `<transition>`

Here an example:

```
 <transition name="slide">
    <div class="col-12 settings p-3 position-fixed" class="settings" v-if="isVisible">
         <h4>Settings</h4>
    </div>
 </transition>
```

CSS class

```
.slide-enter-active, .slide-leave-active {
  transition: transform .5s;
}
.slide-enter, .slide-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}
.settings {
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Its really not that hard

Take a look: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: I know about but I didn't considered this way. I will give it a try. Usually I use transition only for vue-router views. Thanks for the help

Comment: @fed3vt even in the doc they used html elements

Comment: it's working fine with the transition but the transition effect isn't smooth as I was expecting

Comment: After some tests, to have a smooth effect I've modified the CSS to include an animation for slide in and another for slide out. Now all works as expected. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that, because you are using v-if, the element is only being rendered when the condition isVisible === True. This means that it is being rendered with the conditional 'show' class already applied, therefore no transition.

You could use the v-show directive instead of v-if, this makes the element hidden but rendered until the condition is true. (more info [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)).

```js
 <div 
  class="col-12 settings p-3 position-fixed" 
  :class="{ 'show': isVisible }" 
  ref="settings" 
  v-show="isVisible">
      <h4>Settings</h4>
  </div>
```

If you want to do more with transitions, I suggest looking up vue-transitions - documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) - this allows you to assign css to the element during its rendering states, i.e. what styles apply as it enters and when it leaves.

See the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64207437/12873927) for an example of how to do this with vue transition.

Comment: I've already tested with the `v-show` but the transition will not be applied. I need to try with vue transition